# TLS certificate validation failure

Tags: python, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I set up a Mosquitto broker in a Raspberry Pi and created self-signed TLS server certificate with OpenSSL. Configuration works as **I can connect successfully** with Moquitto client from terminal, as well as from MQTTBox and MQTT.fx.

However when trying to connect with Python and Paho-MQTT following error

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# SETTINGS & CONSTANTS
(...)
TLS_CA = "./tls/mqtt.crt"

# MQTT CALLBACKS
(...)

# INIT & CONNECT CLIENT
client = mqtt.Client(DEVICE_ID)
(...)
client.tls_set(TLS_CA)                                                                     
client.username_pw_set(MQTT_USER, MQTT_PSWD)                                               
client.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, MQTT_KEEPALIVE)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 804, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

I've tried many things:

1) Insert self-signed certificate into Raspbian ca-certificates

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
sudo cp mqtt.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/mqtt.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

2) Play with Paho's tls_set() options. I think `ca_certs=mqtt.crt` and `tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1` should be enough.

3) Use `tls_insecure_set(True)`. I know this is not a valid solution, but I just wanted to try if something happen. Result is still CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error

4) Use Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.4.2

I've actually run out of ideas

Comment: You tried with `ca_certs` and not `ca_cert` right? (just checking if this is a typo)

Comment: It was a typo, I fix it in my description

Comment: Can you try sniffing the beginning of the TLS handshake to see exactly which certificates are sent? Also try first to connect from Python just with `ssl`/`PyOpenSSL` modules to see if you get the TLS handshake successfully in this case, to see if the problem is in `Paho-MQTT` or not. You are sure that MQTT_HOST matches  what is in the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time trying and reading everywhere I realized the problem was caused by self-signed certificates. I generated new certificates with different Common Names for CA and broker and everything seems to work fine.